# Override Plugin install script in the main application

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

In my Grails application, I need to override the _Install.groovy of a plugin (Third Party plugin) without making that plugin in-line. Normally If we want to override any class file or gsp we create the overriden one in the application following the same hierarchical structure. Not sure about _Install.groovy. Any ideas?

Comment: There does not seem to be any way to override plugin scripts, docs does not explain it anywhere

Comment: You have the PluginInstalled event, according to the docs it is "Called after a plugin has been installed". Maybe this event helps you? http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/commandLine.html#events

Comment: No pluginInstalled event wont work for us either. Since during plugin installation only we get some issues, so I want to by-pass that install script. Thanks for replies!